# Not able to import project in adt eclipse

Tags: android, ubuntu, adt

My adt eclipse in ubuntu was working fine but suddenly some problem came.I was trying to import project from existing folder.But it is not working.When I click finish in the window, nothing happpens.Please Help me.

Comment: Did you try resetting the computer? Upgrading to the latest Eclipse version? Update SDK's?

Comment: restart eclipse and try it